# how to integrate ZSH and (i)python?

Tags: python, shell, zsh, ipython

I have been in love with `zsh` for a long time, and more recently I have been discovering the advantages of the `ipython` interactive interpreter over `python` itself. Being able to *cd*, to *ls*, to *run* or to *!* is indeed very handy. But now it feels weird to have such a clumsy shell when in ipython, and I wonder how I could integrate my zsh and my ipython better.

Of course, I could rewrite my .zshrc and all my scripts in python, and emulate most of my shell world from ipython, but it doesn't feel right. And I am obviously not ready to use ipython as a main shell anyway.

So, here comes my question: how do you work efficiently between your shell and your python command-loop ? Am I missing some obvious integration strategy ? Should I do all that in emacs ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I asked this question on the zsh list and this answer worked for me. YMMV.

In genutils.py after the line

> if not debug:

Remove the line:

> stat = os.system(cmd)

Replace it with:

> stat =
>   subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True,executable='/bin/zsh')

you see, the problem is that that "!" call uses os.system to run it, which defaults to manky old /bin/sh .

Like I said, it worked for me, although I'm not sure what got borked behind the scenes.

Comment: yes, this indeed changes the shell for zsh ; but my .zshrc is still not read though, and I do not get my aliases/functions. do you ?

Comment: .zshrc is only read in an interactive shell.  

/bin/zsh -i is how you force zsh to be interactive thus reading the .zshrc I wish I'd known this last year.

Comment: Anything that applies to non-interactive shells should just be devined in .zshenv instead of .zshrc, rather than using `zsh -i`. .zshrc should be used for things like prompts.

Comment: You could also use the $SHELL environment variable, I think this is safer than hard-coding the shell executable path:

`import os`,
`stat = subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True,executable=os.environ['SHELL'])`

Comment: @liefdenby Your answer shouts "It Should Be Done This Way!" Let us pray it is so.

Comment: Where is `genutils.py`? I do `find / -name genutils.py 2> /dev/null` and get nothing on my ubuntu machine with IPython installed.

Answer (score 7):

You can run shell commands by starting them with an exclamation mark and capture the output in a python variable. Example: listing directories in your `/tmp` directory:

```
ipy> import os
ipy> tmplist = !find /tmp
ipy> [dir for dir in tmplist if os.path.isdir(dir)]
```

The list object is a special ipython object with several useful methods. Example: listing files ending with *.pdf*

```
ipy> tmplist.grep(lambda a: a.endswith('.pdf')) # using a lambda
ipy> tmplist.grep('\.pdf$') # using a regexp
```

There is a lot of things you can do by reading the list of magic commands:

```
ipy> %magic
```

See the [shell section](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#enhanced-interactive-python-shell) of the Ipython documentation.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I had figured that out, my question was more of a "power user" one (even if I don't consider myself an ipython power user yet).

For example, I'm quite annoyed that this exclamation mark syntax uses /bin/sh to execute commands, and not my usual shell. All my (shell) aliases, functions and customozations are thus lost. Any idea about how to make ipython use a different shell ?

Another annoying feature is the tab-completion: for example, "run myscr<TAB>" will find "myscript.py" but not a file called "myscript". 

Long story short, I'm still not convinced by ipython...

Comment: Yes, but with no luck: obviously my shell aliases are still not there, and "run myscri<TAB>" still doesn't find "myscript" without .py suffix.

I think that for the moment, I will stick to zsh in the terminal, and to the regular python interpreter in an emacs buffer. This way, I get proper completion everywhere, and I don't have to mess with ipython. maybe one day...